# How to use UIViewController in non-modal way?

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, modal-dialog, tableview

I'm having a uiscrollview with 3 slots, each holding a tableview with different data.

As you can imagine, handling 3 tableviews on the same viewcontroller is a bit of a mess.
So I was thinking about using multiple uiviewcontrollers to handle the different logic required for each tableview. However I can't seem to do this since uiviewcontrollers load in a modal way/blocking the entire previous view: this leaves me unable to continue to use the uiscrollview placed on my root view controller.

Is there a way to solve this? Or pack UIView logic and behavior in some sort of stub/hidden uiviewcontroller that doesn't block the view below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at this the wrong way. Separating your tableviews is a good idea, but there is no need to use a view controller.

Let's say you have three tableViews: tableViewOne, tableViewTwo, and tabelViewThree.

The problem (as I understand it) is that all of your logic code (datasource and delegate methods) are getting all mixed up. So, just create a subclass of NSObject for each tableView and use that object for the datasource/delegate. Just make sure you set the datasource/delegate properties of the tableView to the right object.

Comment: It worked, thx. There was no need to use a UIViewController as you said. I created a subclass of NSObject - to serve as a controller for the tableview - implementing the delegate and datasource methods of UITableView. I then added a property for accessing a NSMutableArray in this object that was fed data from my main UIViewController. The 3 UITableViews, came perfectly fed with different data.

Comment: Glad to have helped. Best of luck to you and your project.